# Webcam and drivers for it don’t work in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, webcam

The webcam on my Asus G51Jx doesn’t work now that I’ve upgraded to Windows 8.

I’ve looked on the Asus site, but they don’t seem to have drivers for Windows 8 yet (at least not for my laptop).

I've tried the following without success:

- Using the Windows 7 drivers, but the installers aren’t compatible
- Automatically detecting new hardware with the Metro Device Manager
- Automatically detecting new hardware with the classic Windows Device Manager
- Using all available drivers for my laptop on the Asus site

Does anyone have any ideas that don’t revolve around waiting for official release drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird thing about Windows 8 I guess... I had a function Key on my keyboard. I've **NEVER** used this before to enable or disable the web cam. But I had to hit it to enable it.

When it's disabled, it's like it can't even see the hardware in my device manager. It's as if it's physically removed. But when it's enabled, it works okay.

Answer (score 0):

Install drivers from the bundled DVD. I have the same laptop and when I installed Windows 8 Professional, all drivers worked.

You can also follow [this guide](http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus-reviews-owners-lounges/487236-asus-g51jx-owners-lounge-54.html#post6613910) to install drivers.